A <div> shifts down when a margin is added to a child <p> element
I have a <section> with a background color, and this element is entirely covered by a translucent <div>. Within the <div>, I have a paragraph with a top margin. Here’s my code:


.header-st {
  height: 40vh;
  border: 1px black solid;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.header-transp {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(228, 17, 17, 0.5);
  /* border: 1px black solid; /**/
}
<header class="header-st">
  <div class="header-transp">
    <p style="margin-top: 20px">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, cum tenetur illum quas, voluptatem enim numquam maxime, ipsam hic iusto ducimus corrupti minima dolorem? Reprehenderit blanditiis molestiae obcaecati sed similique!
    </p>
  </div>
</header>



The problem is that the <div> shifts downwards, as if the margin was applied to it instead of the paragraph. If I uncomment the border in the .header-transp CSS rule, the page behaves as expected, with the margin applied to the paragraph and not the <div> - but the <div> shifts down the same amount as the border's width. Adding a non-zero padding to the <div> yields the same result. Quite curious!
By consulting a renowned expert (Google Bard), I learned about the concept of margin collapsing and that margins are meant to separate elements on the same level, not child elements from their parents. Thus, the same expert told me that if I added any gap between the a <section> and its child (the <div>) the problem would be solved. That could even be a null margin (i.e., adding margin-top: 0; to the .header-transp class). Conceptually, this makes sense, but didn't work. A non-zero margin didn't work as well.
The only way I found to solve the issue was eliminating the border in both classes (.header-st and .header-transp) - but I still want a border around these elements.
I need help to understand and fix that.
